# Objective C writetoFile not work when get file path from textfied (file browser)

Tags: objective-c, macos, writetofile

Im trying to save the file into the path, which I manual input into text field or select from FileBrowser. However it doesn't work.

If I drop path to textfield then it working fine. Could you help me.

```
- (IBAction)btnRawDataPath:(id)sender {
    _txtLog.stringValue = @"";
    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];

    // Multiple files not allowed
    [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];

    // Can't select a directory
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Display the dialog. If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSModalResponseOK )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        NSArray* urls = [openDlg filenames];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        for(int i = 0; i < [urls count]; i++ )
        {
            //fileList.push_back(std::string([[[urls objectAtIndex:i] path] UTF8String]));
            NSString* url = [urls objectAtIndex:i] ;
            NSLog(@"Url: %@", url);
           _txtRawDataPath.stringValue = url;
        }
    }
}
```

// EXCUTE

```
NSString *filePath = [_txtRawDataPath.stringValue stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"outputFIle.csv"];



NSData* settingsData;
settingsData = [mainString dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([settingsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES ])
    NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
```

Comment: Please describe "it doesn't work". What is the path from the text field and what is the path from the open panel? Try `URLs` instead of `filenames` and `writeToURL:` instead of `writeToFile:`. Don't use paths, use URLs.

Comment: filepath: "/Users/Peter/Downloads/" <from textfield and openpanel are same>.

Comment: How I can convert NSString filepath to URLs.

Comment: I did try to convert filepath to URLs by: NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; and using WritetoURL however still not work at all.

Comment: I tried your code and it works, although `-[NSOpenPanel filenames]` is deprecated.

Comment: Yes I found problem, might some kind of access issue. I disable Sandbox then it working fine.